# hide and show datatable in server side data source

Tags: jquery, datatable

This is my sample code to load data table server side source.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );
} );
```

Now I want to hide the table when ajax try to fetch data from server, after successfully fetching the data will show the table again. Is there any way to do so? What I have found, I can not change the style of processing and can not hide the table entirely.